# How to get intent data from a runnable back to a calling intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, runnable

I need to start a thread that downloads an image from the web, then return the location of that image on external drive via an intent to the calling activity.  In this example I am starting in MainActivity, creating an intent that calls the DownloadImage class where the runnable and thread are located.  That runnable in turn calls a utility class to do all of the work off of the UI thread.

Where I am stuck is how to get that work result back to MainActivity.  When I run this code I get a null for my intent data.  Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
MainActivity.class 

...      

Uri urlData = Uri.parse("http://www.testUrl.com/image.png");

    Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(this, DownloadImage.class);
    downloadIntent.putExtra("imageUri", urlData);

    startActivityForResult(downloadIntent, DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            Intent galleryIntent = makeGalleryIntent(data.toString());

            startActivity(galleryIntent);
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || requestCode != DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Activity did not complete correctly.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


---------------------------------------------------------
DownloadImage.class

...


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Uri data = getIntent().getData();

        Runnable downloadRunnable = new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

           Intent i = new Intent(DownloadImage.this, MainActivity.class)                
           i.putExtra("urlData", DownloadUtils.downloadImage(DownloadImageActivity.this, data));
        } 
// downloadImage takes in a Uri object and context to create a location on disk for the result.  returns a uri object.          
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        };

        thread = new Thread (downloadRunnable);
        thread.start();
        finish();

}
```

Comment: Where overriding `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: I've added it, but onActivityResult isn't the problem.  I am getting null for my intent data in the DownloadImage class.

Answer (score 0):

Other than creating you own `Runnable`, I suggest you use [Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download your images from the web.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(DownloadImage.this);
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();

      //this method will be running on UI thread
      pdLoading.setMessage("\tDownloading...");
      pdLoading.show();
  }
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //can access params like params[1], params[2] ...
      //this method will be running on background thread so don't update UI  frome here
      //do your long running http tasks here,you dont want to pass argument and u can access the parent class' variable url over here


      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      //this method will be running on UI thread

      pdLoading.dismiss();
  }
```

}

Then you can execute the AsyncTask like `new DownloadImage().execute();` Note that you can pass any parameters you like here to the execute(); read more about it on [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I would love to but this is for a class and I need to use a Handler, Message, Runnable thread scheme to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You must call startActivityForResult with the intent and implement the onActivityResult for capture the info that come from DownloadImage.

In Activity MainActivity you forget this line:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

See the example:

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, DownloadImage.class), 1);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // do something
   }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

For send the info to MainActivity you must call setResult with the info in your bundle and call finish().

Activity DownloadImage:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("---your info---");

    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtras(bundle));
finish();
```

Read the section "Starting Activities and Getting Results" from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: What if my bundle is not a string?  I'm working with Uri data, not strings.  The final Uri data = getIntent().getData(); command is giving me a null.